# Can't pass sys.argv[0] to subprocess.call

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, subprocess, sys

I'm trying to call a `python` script from the terminal that itself calls a `.jar`. Note that this java program takes in one argument (a String) and writes a `.txt` file with the contents of this string.

My attempt is to go (in `test.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['java','-jar',sys.argv[0],sys.argv[1]])
```

and then in the terminal type:

```
python test.py test.jar Hello
```

However, I get the error `Invalid or corrupt jarfile test.jar`. The funny thing is the following will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['java','-jar','test.jar',sys.argv[0]])
```

Followed by:

```
python test.py Hello
```

Answer (score 3):

`sys.argv[0]` is actually the name of your Python file, since it's the first argument you give after `python`. So in your call, you want to be using `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]`.

My `test.py`:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
```

Running `test.py`:

```
marius@devils-creek ~   python test.py
# Output 
test.py
```